# How can I speed up this double for loop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Below is my code.  The issue I am having is with the double for loop where it goes through each theta and then each phi.  This is a total of 65,160 iterations.  My entire code takes about 45 seconds while that double for loop takes about 44.5 of those 45 seconds.

This is an issue because I need to run this code over 125 times causing my full code to take about an hour and a half to run in total.

I am fairly new to python and was hoping someone more familiar with python and potentially pandas could help me find a more efficient way to do this.

As an FYI, data1 and data2 are DataFrames with size (65160,6) that contain data I pull out and use in the E_phase and E_magnitude dataframes as seen in the double for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import time

data1 = pd.read_csv(path1,delimiter = '\t',skiprows=3)
data1['Phi'] = np.rad2deg(data1['Phi'])
data1['Theta'] = np.rad2deg(data1['Theta'])

data2 = pd.read_csv(path2,delimiter = '\t',skiprows=3)
data2['Phi'] = np.rad2deg(data2['Phi'])
data2['Theta'] = np.rad2deg(data2['Theta'])

E_PHI_AMP_IDX = 2
E_THETA_AMP_IDX = 3
E_PHI_PHASE_IDX = 4
E_THETA_PHASE_IDX = 5



PHI_COLUMN_IDX = 0
THETA_COLUMN_IDX = 1
VALUE_COLUMN_IDX = 2
TOTAL_THETA_VALUES = (180 + 1)
TOTAL_PHI_VALUES = (360)
TOTAL_ROW_COUNT = (TOTAL_THETA_VALUES * TOTAL_PHI_VALUES);


# pre-allocate arrays needed by ECC computation function
zero_data = np.zeros((TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,3))

E_magnitude_theta_1 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()
E_phase_theta_1 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()

E_magnitude_phi_1 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()
E_phase_phi_1 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()

E_magnitude_theta_2 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()
E_phase_theta_2 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()

E_magnitude_phi_2 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()
E_phase_phi_2 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()

for theta in range(TOTAL_THETA_VALUES):
    for phi in range(TOTAL_PHI_VALUES):
        row_idx = phi * TOTAL_THETA_VALUES + theta
        
        #populate antenna 1 E_Theta arrays
        
        E_magnitude_theta_1.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_magnitude_theta_1.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        E_phase_theta_1.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_phase_theta_1.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        gain = data1.loc[row_idx][E_THETA_AMP_IDX]
        linear_gain = 10**(gain/20)
        angle = data1.loc[row_idx][E_THETA_PHASE_IDX]
        E_magnitude_theta_1.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = linear_gain
        E_phase_theta_1.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = angle
        
        
        #populate antenna 1 E_Phi arrays
        E_magnitude_phi_1.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_magnitude_phi_1.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        E_phase_phi_1.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_phase_phi_1.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        gain = data1.loc[row_idx][E_PHI_AMP_IDX]
        linear_gain = 10**(gain/20)
        angle = data1.loc[row_idx][E_PHI_PHASE_IDX]
        E_magnitude_phi_1.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = linear_gain
        E_phase_phi_1.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = angle
        
        #populate antenna 2 E_Theta arrays
        E_magnitude_theta_2.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_magnitude_theta_2.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        E_phase_theta_2.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_phase_theta_2.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        gain = data2.loc[row_idx][E_THETA_AMP_IDX]
        linear_gain = 10**(gain/20)
        angle = data2.loc[row_idx][E_THETA_PHASE_IDX]
        E_magnitude_theta_2.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = linear_gain
        E_phase_theta_2.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = angle

        #populate antenna 2 E_Phi arrays
        E_magnitude_phi_2.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_magnitude_phi_2.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        E_phase_phi_2.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_phase_phi_2.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        gain = data2.loc[row_idx][E_PHI_AMP_IDX]
        linear_gain = 10**(gain/20)
        angle = data2.loc[row_idx][E_PHI_PHASE_IDX]
        E_magnitude_phi_2.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = linear_gain
        E_phase_phi_2.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = angle
```

I am unsure how to improve the speed of this or if there I am out of luck and just have to accept the time a process like this will take.

Comment: Can you share the data or add some code to generate equivalent data? If you add code to generate representative data then make the number of rows a variable.

Comment: put it into a numpy array and vectorise like this: https://youtu.be/e1zRI46ZSUo

Comment: iterating rows of a dataframe is slow.  Working with the underlying numpy arrays is much faster.

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
TOTAL_ROW_COUNT = (TOTAL_THETA_VALUES * TOTAL_PHI_VALUES);
# pre-allocate arrays needed by ECC computation function
zero_data = np.zeros((TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,3))

E_magnitude_theta_1 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()
E_phase_theta_1 = pd.DataFrame(zero_data).copy()
...
```

Here you make 8 dataframes with `TOTAL_ROW_COUNT` rows,and 3 columns each.
And with the double loop you iterate over each row (the phi loop nested inside the theta loop).

```
arr = np.zeros((8, TOTAL_THETA_VALUES, TOTAL_PHI_VALUES, 3))
```

is a 4d array that can hold all those values.

```
for theta in range(TOTAL_THETA_VALUES):
    for phi in range(TOTAL_PHI_VALUES):
        # row_idx = phi * TOTAL_THETA_VALUES + theta
        Arow = arr[:,theta, phi,:] 
        # the equivalent of indexing all 8 frames with `row_idx`
         
        #populate antenna 1 E_Theta arrays
        
        # E_magnitude_theta_1.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        Arow[0,[PHI_COLUMN_IDX, THETA_COLUMN_IDX]] = phi, theta
        # E_magnitude_theta_1.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        # but wait you also assign the same values to the `Arow[1,...]`

        #E_phase_theta_1.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        #E_phase_theta_1.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta

        #gain = data1.loc[row_idx][E_THETA_AMP_IDX]
        # data1 is a 3d array, you could index in the same way
        data1[theta, phi, ...]


        linear_gain = 10**(gain/20)
        angle = data1.loc[row_idx][E_THETA_PHASE_IDX]
        E_magnitude_theta_1.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = linear_gain
        E_phase_theta_1.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = angle
```

and yet more expensive dataframe indexing and assigning the same phi and theta values.

```
        #populate antenna 1 E_Phi arrays
        E_magnitude_phi_1.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_magnitude_phi_1.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        E_phase_phi_1.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_phase_phi_1.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        gain = data1.loc[row_idx][E_PHI_AMP_IDX]
        linear_gain = 10**(gain/20)
        angle = data1.loc[row_idx][E_PHI_PHASE_IDX]
        E_magnitude_phi_1.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = linear_gain
        E_phase_phi_1.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = angle
```

more repeats:

```
        #populate antenna 2 E_Theta arrays
        E_magnitude_theta_2.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_magnitude_theta_2.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        E_phase_theta_2.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_phase_theta_2.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        gain = data2.loc[row_idx][E_THETA_AMP_IDX]
        linear_gain = 10**(gain/20)
        angle = data2.loc[row_idx][E_THETA_PHASE_IDX]
        E_magnitude_theta_2.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = linear_gain
        E_phase_theta_2.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = angle
```

and more

```
        #populate antenna 2 E_Phi arrays
        E_magnitude_phi_2.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_magnitude_phi_2.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        E_phase_phi_2.at[row_idx,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = phi
        E_phase_phi_2.at[row_idx,THETA_COLUMN_IDX] = theta
        gain = data2.loc[row_idx][E_PHI_AMP_IDX]
        linear_gain = 10**(gain/20)
        angle = data2.loc[row_idx][E_PHI_PHASE_IDX]
        E_magnitude_phi_2.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = linear_gain
        E_phase_phi_2.at[row_idx,VALUE_COLUMN_IDX] = angle
I
```

In compiled code, repeating blocks of code isn't too expensive, but in interpreted python, and especially when working with dataframes, all these `.at` and `.loc` calls a expensive, and add up.

It may that we can set

arr[:,:,:,PHI_COLUMN_IDX] = np.arange(phi_count)

That is set all `phi` without iteration.  Similarly for all theta.

Only your `value_idx` column differs across the 8 frames.

Comment: Thank you for all this information.  Using a combination of things you wrote here I was able to get the code from taking 45 seconds to about .4 seconds per iteration.  I used a 4d array as well as converted my data1 and data2 to numpy arrays and used indexing rather than pandas .loc function and I indexed all the phi and theta outside of the loop as you described.